# Category related -> excerpt, title and thumb in sidebar on article page

Tags: categories

I've done some research and tried different solutions but this snippet gets me the actual post content in sidebar, when on a single/article page, from the category the post belogs to.

But I need to show the excerpt instead of the whole text and also a thumbnail and can't figure out how to add them.

Any suggestions please?

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
echo '<ul><li>';
foreach ($categories as $c) {
    if (strpos(get_permalink($post->ID), $c->slug) !== false) {
        echo '<a href="/' . $c->slug . '/">' . $c->name . '</a>';
        $current_cat = $c->cat_ID;
    }
}
$posts = get_posts(array('cat' => $current_cat));
if (!empty($posts)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($posts as $p) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($p->ID) . '">' . $p->post_title . '</a></li>';
        echo $p->post_content;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
echo '</li></ul>';
?>
```

Or another approach maybe? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution and modified it for my needs, maybe there are people looking for same thing, so there you go:

```
<?php
if ( is_single() ) {
  $categories = get_the_category();
  if ($categories) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      $cat = $category->cat_ID;
      $args=array(
        'cat' => $cat,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'=>3,
        'offset'=>1,
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
      );
      $my_query = null;
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<h2>More in this section</h2>';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="cat-related-articles">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb'); ?>          

<p class="sidebar-article-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link 

to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

<?php the_excerpt(5); ?>  

          </div>
         <?php
        endwhile;
      } //if ($my_query)
    } //foreach ($categories
  } //if ($categories)
  wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
} //if (is_single())
?>
```

Now, my problem is:

```
'posts_per_page'=>3,
'offset'=>1,
```

They don't work. I am trying to leave out and not display the post I am currently on. Remember, if I click on an article article, this code in the sidebar would display the title, thumb and excerpt of 3 more articles from the same category.

So, **how do I make it not to display the post** I am currently viewing?

Another thing, I the article I am on belongs to 2 categories, that code will show me posts from each category. **How do I get rid of this?!**

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your code and fixing it up but it wasn't having any luck. Try this out and let me know how it works for you:

```
<?php
  $args = array( 
    'numberposts' => 3, 
    'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 
    'category' => '' 
    );
  ?>
<?php
  $postslist = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
  ?>
  <h2>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
  </h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, and sorry for my late reply. Well, yours is displaying me the thumb, title and excerpt but the title and the photo is the same, is just the excerpt which is changed accordingly. I think that means that the function is used well, the args are alright but the foreach is not functioning as it should, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try plugin [Mini Loops](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mini-loops/). It has the features you need. Also checkboxes "Get posts from current category (if archive)?" and "Get posts from first category (if single)?".

Comment: That looks fantastic, will use it next time. I have now lost way too much time on this and not only that, but I would really like to understand the problem properly so will try and fix my code. Thanks!